# How to store last value of iteration?

Tags: python

Im new to python and just a quick question.

I have created a for loop which runs through the values of a list, then converts into an angle of a circle (multiply by 360). What I want to do now is store that value of the previous iteration. eg, after running this code, I would get

```
79.2
118.08
21.6
29.52
10.8
7.2
7.2
```

The Code:

```
for i in range(len(percentages_minus_index)):
    other_segment_angles = percentages_minus_index[i] * 360
```

So basically, if the first value is 79.2, I want to store in a variable in the loop, and then replace it after the next iteration. eg.

iteration 1: 79.2, previous value = nothing
iteration 2: 118.08, previous = 79.2

.... etc etc

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use another variable, which can store the previous value and also, a better way to loop a list would be, like this

```
previous = None
for percentage in percentages_minus_index:
    other_segment_angles = percentage * 360
    print previous
    previous = other_segment_angles
```

But I wonder why you would want to use that, as your program doesn't depend on the previous value. For example, if I want to find the sum of `n` numbers (without using `sum`), then

```
previous = 0
for number in range(10):
    temp = previous + number
    previous = temp
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just a part of my program, that larger part is to make a pie chart that changes depending on a list of given values.

Comment: Just one more quick question, I have now implemented your solution and it works fine, but now  I want to try something else. Do you know how it would be possible for me to keep track of the TOTAL of the previous iterations? Eg, iteration 1 is 79, iteration 2 is 108, total of two is iteration1+iteration2, then keep going?

Comment: @user3496101 You mean, you want all the intermediate results?

Comment: I mean, i want the total values of the iterations at every step, so iteration 1 = 79, total = 79, iteration 2 = 108, total = iteration 1 + iteration 2, iteration 3 = 45, total = iteration1 + iteration2 + iteration 3 and so on and so forth. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @user3496101 Can you please edit your question with a sample input and expected output?

Comment: yeah sorry, i accidentally pressed enter

Comment: @user3496101 I think that is what the second program in my answer will give you, if you print `previous`

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
percentages_minus_index = [23,14,16,1]

previousValues = [None]*len(percentages_minus_index)

for i in range(len(percentages_minus_index)):
    other_segment_angles = percentages_minus_index[i] * 360
    print(other_segment_angles)
    if i > 0:
        previousValue[i] = percentages_minus_index[i-1] * 360
    print(previousValue[i])
```

Comment: Yeah thats the ticket, it prints the previous value. Would it be possible for me to use the previousvalue variable? example, im trying to work with angles, but i have to add the value of the previous angle to the next one to continue. thanks

Comment: Yeah, you can use previousValue like any other variable. It's an array, so previousValue[0] is the previous value of the first element in the percentages_minus_index (we've called that None) and previousValue[1] is the previous value of the second element and so on. previousValue[1] + previousValue[2] is a perfectly fine operation.

Answer (score 0):

percentages_minus_index = [23,14,16,1]

previousValues = [None]*len(percentages_minus_index)

for i in range(len(percentages_minus_index)):
other_segment_angles = percentages_minus_index[i] * 360
print(other_segment_angles)
if i > 0:
previousValue[i] = percentages_minus_index[i-1] * 360
print(previousValue[i])

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also, @wjh2000 suggested an edit for your answer but 2 reviewers rejected it. How this version of the answer is better than the previous one?